# how to keep using Google Maps in browser and avoid launching the app?

Tags: google-maps, dolphin-browser

If I point my browser (Doplhin browser) to http://maps.google.com it automatically opens the Google Maps app.

Is there a way to avoid this and keep using the site through the browser?

If it matters, I'm on Android Lollipop on Sony Xperia Z3 compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes absolutely. If your Dolphin Browser is up-to-date, just follow this step -
**`Open Browser > Settings > Advanced > More > Open in app > You'll know what to do after that ;)`**