# How to keep using Google Maps in Chrome browser and avoid launching the app?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google-maps

If I point my browser (Chrome browser) to http://maps.google.com it automatically opens the Google Maps app.

Is there a way to avoid this and keep using the site through the browser?

If it matters, I'm on Android Lollipop on Samsung tablet.

I couldnt find the settings corollary in Chrome described in this post re same concern in Dolphin [how to keep using Google Maps in browser and avoid launching the app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109042/how-to-keep-using-google-maps-in-browser-and-avoid-launching-the-app). Is it in flags?

Comment: Go to your phone's *Settings* app -> *Apps -> All apps -> Maps -> Open by default -> Open supported links-> Don't open in this app*. See if you can do this and works out for you.

Comment: You could use the "request desktop site" option and try loading Google Maps.

Comment: Thx, Firelord. That did it.

Answer (score 1):

The trick mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/allo/forum/AAAA23IuijkwgaWiEllo_M/?hl=en) works for me on Chrome `61.0.3163.98`, the latest on Play Store

> open chrome and go to     `chrome://flags/#tab-management-experiment-type`
>
> Click the drop down under Switch preferred flavor of Herb
>
> Change it to `disabled`
>
> Click the blue restart button that appears at the bottom of the screen

Alternatively, you can use [Chromer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=arun.com.chromer) , which is a light weight version of Chrome. It has the advantage of launching browser from apps and quickly reverting to the app without losing place from where you clicked

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold on the link and press "open in new tab" in the drop down menu

Tested on Samsung S8 and galaxy tab on google chrome and Samsung internet.